# Transforming Shapely Polygon and MultiPolygon objects

Tags: python, coordinate-system, shapely, pyproj

Is there an easy way of transforming Shapely objects (namely, Polygons and MultiPolygons) from one projection to another without having to dig around and extract coordinates by hand?

In fact, I don't even care if they are Shapely objects at this point, I just want to pass features and a projection, and get a reprojected set of features back.

Does this sort of functionality exist, or must it be hand coded?

Comment: I believe that's out of the scope of Shapely, you may want to look into Fiona. [`fiona.transform`](https://github.com/Toblerity/Fiona/blob/master/fiona/transform.py) looks to have what you need.

Answer (score 82):

While shapely doesn't natively understand coordinate systems,
[`shapely.ops.transform()`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html?highlight=transform#shapely.ops.transform) can do that along with `pyproj`. If `pyproj.Proj` can understand your both of your coordinate systems, then it can be made into a function that shapely can transform with.

From the shapely [docs](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html?highlight=transform#shapely.ops.transform):

#### pyproj >= 2.1.0

```py
import pyproj

from shapely.geometry import Point
from shapely.ops import transform

wgs84_pt = Point(-72.2495, 43.886)

wgs84 = pyproj.CRS('EPSG:4326')
utm = pyproj.CRS('EPSG:32618')

project = pyproj.Transformer.from_crs(wgs84, utm, always_xy=True).transform
utm_point = transform(project, wgs84_pt)
```

#### pyproj < 2.1

```
from functools import partial
import pyproj
from shapely.ops import transform

project = partial(
    pyproj.transform,
    pyproj.Proj(init='epsg:4326'), # source coordinate system
    pyproj.Proj(init='epsg:26913')) # destination coordinate system

g2 = transform(project, g1)  # apply projection
```

Comment: If you do not want to use the `itertools` module you can do `project = lambda x, y: pyproj.transform(pyproj.Proj(init='epsg:4326'), pyproj.Proj(init='epsg:26913'), x, y)` and then `g2 = transform(project, g1)`.

Comment: This suggested answer is for pyproj1 whereas there is now a preferred transformation for pyproj2 using `Transformer`. See here: http://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/gotchas.html

Comment: I found Nick O'Dell's answer below (https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/328642) to be much faster.

Comment: Checking my knowledge: wgs84_pt describes the coordinates 72.2495W (longitude) and 43.886N due to the `always_xy=True`.  For `always_xy=False` lat/lon would need to be swapped when constructing the initial point.  Is this correct?

Answer (score 31):

If you're using pyproj2, it's much easier to use a Transformer. Here's an example:

```
import pyproj
from shapely.ops import transform

project = pyproj.Transformer.from_proj(
    pyproj.Proj(init='epsg:4326'), # source coordinate system
    pyproj.Proj(init='epsg:26913')) # destination coordinate system

# g1 is a shapley Polygon

g2 = transform(project.transform, g1)  # apply projection
```

This is also much faster, becase pyproj does not need to recreate the projection for every point.

Comment: _Way_ faster than the accepted answer!

Comment: Really much faster! fantastic.Great!

Comment: WIth pyproj 3.5.0, I had to additionally set `always_xy` to `True`.
https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/api/transformer.html#pyproj.transformer.Transformer.from_proj

Answer (score 14):

While not a Shapely solution, using GeoPandas allows for relatively straightforward projection. For example, if we want to convert a shapefile to ESPG 4326:

```
import geopandas as gpd

HabModelEnviro = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file('data/HabModelEnviro.shp').replace({-999: None})

HabModelEnviroWGS84 = HabModelEnviro.to_crs({'proj':'longlat', 'ellps':'WGS84', 'datum':'WGS84'})
```

Comment: Geopandas uses Shapely (look at geodataframe.py for example)