# Converting Shapefile points to Lat/Long?

Tags: shapely, pyshp

**Quick Overview of the Project:** I have 9000 records of individuals, each with a coordinate pair in a csv. I also have a shapefile/folder(dbf, prj, sbn, sbx, shp, shx) of municipalities within the range of coordinates. I'd like to know which municipality(shape) in the shapefile corresponds to each record in the csv

**Problem:** When I look at the shapefile in python, the grid isn't lat/long. I subscribed to a trial version of arcGIS to be able to load up the coordinates and look at them, and they map correctly, so I must just be missing something. Attached is my code and the map printed by Python.

How can I transpose my csv coordinates to the map or vice versa?

```
import shapefile as shp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from shapely.geometry import Point

import csv

n = 0
m = 1

coorDict = {}
coor = ''
fileName = 'TestLatLong'

sf = shp.Reader("wcmun/wcmun")
sfRec = sf.records()
plt.figure()
for shape in sf.shapeRecords():
    x = [i[0] for i in shape.shape.points[:]]
    y = [i[1] for i in shape.shape.points[:]]
    plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
plt.figure()


n = 0    
#Then create a dictionary of lat/longs from 'TestLatLong.csv'
```

[image: WestchesterCounty]
The output of all shape records and data in the first shape record above
For comparison, all the data should be roughly in a rectangle from 
(40.881321, -73.926644) to (41.442483, -73.542874), and as you can see this map isn't.

Comment: use shapely and reproject https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/127427/transforming-shapely-polygon-and-multipolygon-objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [metadata](http://giswww.westchestergov.com/Metadata/wcmun.htm#ID0EEAEKA) the boundary shapefile is in New York State Plane East (NAD_1983_StatePlane_New_York_East_FIPS_3101_Feet).

You can use the Project tool in ArcMap to make a new shapefile in WGS 84 Lat/Lon to match your points. [This PDF](http://resourcesupplyllc.com/PDFs/Reproject%20Coordinate%20Systems%20in%20ArcGIS.pdf) walks you through the process.

Comment: This did it, thanks so much- I don't know which coordinate system to use (there are many different options under WGS 84) would you happen to know which one is correct? The one I tried (WGS 84 Web Mercator) is a bit off, otherwise I can just play around until I find the correct one.   Thank you so much though

Comment: It's just "WGS 84". It's under Geographic Coordinate Systems > World > WGS 84. Or search for "4326", its EPSG code.

Comment: You're right I was looking in the wrong spot, thanks so much- this was massively helpful