# Measurement display while creating a vector layer

Tags: qgis, vector-layer, measurements, length, elevation-profile

I am trying to display the measurement tool on QGIS while I am adding a vector to a vector layer I created. I am using EPSG 4326 and I cannot figure out how to use the measurement tool while creating a vector. Currently I am doing research and I need to gather vectors that are 4km in length that showcase a fault line in the direct center, meaning I need to measure 2 km on each side of the fault line and represent it with a vector. I would like to be as accurate as possible and showing the measurement while creating the vector would help a lot. Is there a way to do this in QGIS?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which map projection is suitable for distance measurement purpose in USA?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/349172/which-map-projection-is-suitable-for-distance-measurement-purpose-in-usa)

Answer (score 1):

The Advanced Digitizing Panel will probably be of use. You can show it with

`View > Panels > Advanced Digitizing`.

When your line layer is editable and you have `Add Line Feature` activated, you can then enable `Advanced Digitizing` with this button:

[image]

Once you have begun your line by clicking the first vertex, you can use the [image] button to specify a fixed length for your line.

[image]

However, this won't work if your project and line layer are both in EPSG 4326. It will work if your project is in a projected coordinate system (UTM, or better yet, the local coordinate system) even if your line layer is not. That said, I would recommend working in a local coordinate system rather than EPSG 4326 wherever possible.