# Calculating UTM Zone from UTM coordinates

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates, utm

I'm currently working on a program to transform UTM coordinates into geographic coordinates. In order to do so, I need to obtain the central meridian, which can be obtained by the UTM zone.

How can I calculate the UTM zone from the UTM coordinates?

I know the reference system.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/269518/auto-select-suitable-utm-zone-based-on-grid-intersection?

Comment: I don't think you can go in that direction, all UTM zones have the same range of coordinates

Comment: What do you mean "*I know the reference system*"? If you know the EPSG code, you can work out the UTM Zone from that.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following formula:

```
Zone = ROUND_UP( ( 180+Longitude) / 6 )
```

You have to Round it to the superior integer, the longitude can be the + or - Degrees of the coordinates, or the +/- longitude in decimal format.

Example:

For coordinates: -16,828203, -63,017578

```
Zone = ROUND_UP( ( 180 + (-63,017578) ) / 6 )
Zone = ROUND_UP( ( 116,982422 ) / 6 )
Zone = ROUND_UP( 19,4970703 )
Zone = 20
```

If you need to add N or S, use N if the Latitude is positive and S if it is negative.

Comment: If all the OP has is {UTM_X,UTMY}, there is no way to determine zone. This is effectively a duplicate of the other answer.

Answer (score -2):

I wonder if this might help you, courtesy of [GIS Lounge](https://www.gislounge.com/how-to-calculate-the-boundaries-of-an-utm-zone/#:%7E:text=UTM%20zones%20are%20all%206,to%20obtain%20the%20western%20boundary.):

- UTM zones are all 6 degrees wide and increase from west to east starting at the -180 degree mark.
- Calculate the eastern boundary of any UTM zone by multiplying the zone number by 6 and subtracting 180.
- Subtract 6 degrees to obtain the western boundary.
- Therefore to find the eastern boundary of UTM zone 11: Eastern boundary of zone 11 = (11 * 6) – 180 = -114 degrees.
- Western boundary of zone 11 = -114 – 6 = -120 degrees.

If you take this info, you might be able to work the steps backwards to come to a conclusion.

Comment: If you know which zone you are in then there is no need to calculate anything, if you don't know your zone then there is no way to solve this set of equations uniquely