# Python shapely intersection with buffer in meter

Tags: shapely, python-3

Having a line and a polygon, I use shapely to determine the intersection between the two with a defined buffer. Both the line and the polygon are in WGS84 coordinates, while the buffer is in meter.

```
from shapely.geometry import LineString, Polygon
polygon = Polygon([
    (51.9981816, 4.3677729),
    (51.9983431, 4.3683897),
    (51.9980583, 4.3685846),
    (51.9977777, 4.3687773),
    (51.9976163, 4.3681605),
    (51.9978555, 4.3679964),
    (51.9981816, 4.3677729)
])
line = LineString([
    (51.9976836984107, 4.368050461186726),
    (51.99757198557364, 4.368489603711765),
    (51.9973971301288, 4.3684738261236475)
])
```

Finding the intersection is easy:

```
line.intersection(polygon)
```

Finding the intersection with a buffer in degrees (because coordinates of the objects are in degrees):

```
line.intersection(polygon.buffer(0.2))
```

But how to find the intersection with a buffer in meters? I understand that Shapely is not aware of any coordinate reference system; also no area metric CRS is known (OceanoGraphy is globally).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Shapely knows nothing about your units. Therefore, when you call
`polygon.buffer(0.2)`, 
shapely will buffer the coordinates in polygon by 0.2 units. In your case, these are *not* meters, but degrees.

If you want to buffer in meters, you first need to *reproject your Polygon and Linestring* into a CRS that uses meters. I would use geopandas for this, as it has a convenient .to_crs() method that will do the reprojection quickly. This also requires that you know the CRS of the coordinates you're providing (likely they are epsg:4326). You could also use pyproj, which might be easier if you're not dealing with layers with many polygons:

```
from pyproj import Proj, transform

inProj = Proj(init='epsg:4326')
outProj = Proj(init='epsg:3857')
x1,y1 = -11705274.6374,4826473.6922
x1p,y1p = transform(inProj,outProj,x1,y1)
```

I will leave the looping up to you (you can feed in lists rather than single points, I believe) for all of your coordinates.

**Important**: Choosing the proper CRS is not trivial, and depends on your application and precision needs. I have shown EPSG:3857, which is commonly used by services like Google/Bing maps, etc. However, all projections will have some distortions that vary (usually) with distance from the equator (or the projection's central latitude). One commonly-used option is to determine which UTM Zone your region of interest lies within, then choose the appropriate EPSG.

(EPSG is just a numeric code that maps to a projection.)

Comment: Yes, they are 4326. Could you provide a minimal code example?

Comment: @API Added some code to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Shapely does not know about coordinate systems. You will need to transform your coordinates to a common system. Be careful of potential issues because of the shape of earth.

See [Transforming Shapely Polygon and MultiPolygon objects](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/127427/transforming-shapely-polygon-and-multipolygon-objects) for a possible solution.