# Calculating distance between two Linestring using Python

Tags: python, geojson, distance, shapely, linestring

I have two linestring, each linestring represents a rail road. I am trying to calculate minimum distance between these two linestrings. Which function is efficient to do this?

I have only come across distance function that takes a point and linestring but not 2 linestring.

For e.g.:

```
l1 = LineString([(42.073407, -87.806245), (42.0752508,-87.8080299)])  
l2 = LINESTRING(35.442827 -79.470579, 35.444889 -79.469465, 35.445829 -79.468907, 35.446608 -79.468294, 35.447893 -79.46687)
```

I need the distance between these two shapely objects.

Answer (score 5):

In [The Shapely User Manual](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html) ->  `object.distance(other)`

> Returns the minimum distance (float) to the other geometric object.

```
from shapely.geometry import LineString
l1 = LineString([(42.073407, -87.806245), (42.0752508,-87.8080299)])
from shapely.wkt import loads
l2 = loads(" LINESTRING(35.442827 -79.470579, 35.444889 -79.469465, 35.445829 -79.468907, 35.446608 -79.468294, 35.447893 -79.46687)")
l1.distance(l2)
10.650628707489625
l2.distance(l1)
10.650628707489625
```

Comment: Perfect answer, but the problem is distance here is in degrees. I want to convert degrees to meters/km/mile. I am not able to find a function that does this.

Comment: Any suggestions for converting degrees to meters/km/mile?

Comment: Use , `shapely.ops.transform() ` as in [Transforming Shapely Polygon and MultiPolygon objects](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/127432/2581) for example, but there are many other examples in GIS SE